# Extracting Nested Elements of an R List Generated by Loops

Tags: r, list, nested-lists, r-caret

For lists within lists produced by a loop in R (in this example a list of caret models) I get an object with an unpredictable length and names for inner elements, such as list[[1]][[n repeats of 1]][[2]] where the internal [[1]] is repeated multiple times according to the function's input. In some cases, the length of n is not known, when accessing some older stored lists where input was not saved. While there are ways to work within a list index, like with `list[length(list)]`, there appears to be no way to do this with repeated nested elements. This has made accessing them and passing them to various jobs awkward. I assume there is an efficient way to access them that I have missed, so I'm asking for help to do so, with an example case given below.

The function I'm generating gives out a list from a function that creates several outputs. The final list returned for a function having a complicated output structure is produced by returning something like:

`return(list(listOfModels, trainingData, testingData))`
The listofModels has variable length, depending on input of models given, and potentially other conditions depend on evaluation inside the function. It is made by:

`listOfModels <- list(c(listOfModels, list(trainedModel)))`

Where the "trainedModel" refers to the most recently trained model generated in the loop. The models used and the number of them may vary each time depending on choice. An unfortunate result is a complicated nested lists within a list.

That is,  output[[1]] contains the models I want to access more efficiently, which are themselves list objects, while output[[2]] and output[[3]] are the dataframes used to train and evaluate the models. While accessing the dataframes is simple and has a defined, reproducible structure each time (simply being output[[2]], output[[3]] every time), output[[1]] becomes a mess. E.g., something like the following follows the "output[[1]]":

The only thing I am able to attempt in order to access this is using the fact that [[1]] is attached upon output[[1]] before [[2]]. All of the nested elements except one have a [[2]] at the end. Given the above pattern, there is an ugly solution that works, but is not a desirable format to work with. E.g., after evaluating n models given by a vector of strings called inputList, and a list given as output of the function, "output", I can have [[1]] repeated tens to hundreds of times.

```
for (i in (1:length(inputList)-1)){
 eval(rlang::parse_expr(paste0(c("output", c(rep("[[1]]", 1+i)), "[[2]]" ) , collapse="")) )
}
```

This could be used to use all models for some downstream task like making predictions on new data, or whatever. In cases where the length of the inputList was not known, this could be found out by attempting to repeat this until finding an error, or something similar. This approach can be modified to call on a specific part of the list, for example, a certain model within inputList, if I know the original list input and can find the number for that model. Besides the bulkiness code working this way, compared to some way where I could just call on output[[1]][[n]] using some predictable format for various length n. One of the big problems is when accessing older runs that have been saved where the input list of models was not saved, leaving the length of n unknown. I don't know of any way of using something like `length()` or `lengths()` to count how many nested elements exist within a list. (For my example, output[[1]] is of length 1, no matter how many [[1]] repeat elements there are.)

I believe the simplest solution is to change the way the list is saved by the function, so that I can access it by a systematic reference, however, I have a bunch of old lists which I still want to access and perform some work with, and I'd also like to be able to have better control of working with lists in any case. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

I expected there would be some way to query the structure of nested R lists, which could be used to pass nested elements to separate functions, without having to use very long repetition of brackets.

Comment: Your post is a bit hard to follow. Can you show us examples? Human language is not as precise as data. Are these named or unnamed lists? Do you only need the *first* element in `output[[1]]`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.